# How can Dynamically created element work with For Loop with addEventListener('click', function(){...})

Tags: jquery, html

I know that I have to use somehow I have to use this:

```
$('#parent').on('click', 'button', function(){
    // do something here
})
```

Here's my scenario, I have dynamically created elements that display pictures being uploaded and displayed. Which looks like this:

```
<div id="preview"> //container
   //dynamically created
    <div class="image-dailog"> 
       <a href="#" class="close-thik" id="img_close_btn"></a> //close button
       <img src="img_example.jpg" height= "150px"> //actual image
     </div>

//dynamically created
    <div class="image-dailog"> 
       <a href="#" class="close-thik" id="img_close_btn"></a> //close button
       <img src="img_example.jpg" height= "150px"> //actual image
     </div>

//dynamically created
    <div class="image-dailog"> 
       <a href="#" class="close-thik" id="img_close_btn"></a> //close button
       <img src="img_example.jpg" height= "150px"> //actual image
     </div>

</div>
```

I've created `imageArray[]` to copy FileList items from `<input type=file multiple>` so I can delete items them at will and upload it later. `imageArray.length` is equal to the number of dynamically created elements `.image-dialog`(Parent div of image).

The code below only works if the elements are hardcoded:

```
var image_close_btn = document.getElementsByClassName('close-thik');


        for (var i = 0; i < image_close_btn.length; i++) {
        image_close_btn[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.currentTarget.parentNode.remove(); //this deletes the .image-dialog(My image view) & it works fine
        //delete item at imageArray[i]; 
        //I'm planning make a Method to delete the item in the array which co-responds to image_close_btn[i]

    }, false);
```

My goal here is to be able to delete an item at index i of `imageArray[i]` by clicking the corresponding `image_close_btn[i]`.

Overview, `document.getElementsByClassName('close-thik').length` is equal to `imageArray.length`, so each item in the array is represented by `<div class="image-dailog">`. I need a for-loop get the `index` of `image_close_btn[i]`so when I click it removes the correspending item in `imageArray[i]`.

```
$('#parent').on('click', '.close-thik', function(){
    // do something here
})
```

Comment: this is a jQuery question or a javascript question ?

Comment: Are asking how to delete dynamically created elements AND how to remove an item from an array using an index?

Comment: @ThabisoProsperRamokopu see my updated answer.

Comment: So, this is a jQuery question, not javascript one with a corresponding event delegation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re looking for [Event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) and the parent index.

```
$("#preview").on("click", ".close-link", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // get the index of .image-dialog
  let index = $(this).parent().index();
  // do something with imageArray[index]
})
```

Comment: thanks for replying, My goal here is to be able to delete an item at index i of `imageArray[i]` by clicking the corresponding `image_close_btn[i]`

Comment: See updated answer. This will retrieve the index of the parent node.

Answer (score 0):

The word for this is called [Delegated Events](https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events). When you pass in a selector as the 2nd argument to your `.on` call, you are creating your delegated event.

All that code should be good, maybe you just have to adjust the two selectors you are using for the `parent` and `child` component you want to fire the event on?

```js
// From your example, maybe you want to use '.close-thik' instead of 'button'?
var child_selector = '.close-thik';

// Does the '#parent' element _always_ contain your '.close-thik' elements?
// Maybe you should use a more generic 'body'
var parent_selector = 'body'; 

$(parent_selector).on('click', child_selector, function(e) {
    // do something here
});
```